# Table-cell element to fill free height

Tags: html, css

I bet i saw the answer somewhere, but i can't find.

Pls watch this example http://jsfiddle.net/Ttxx3/

Is there any element that will fill free space between `<p>` element and green `<div>`, so that green `<div>` in every column will fall to bottom?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you could absolutely position the green div within its parent div and attach it to the bottom. http://jsfiddle.net/c5Dpz/

```
div.table > div {
    border: 1px solid #202020;
    display: table-cell;
    position:relative; /* Need this in the parent div */
}
div.table > div div {
       background-color: green;
    bottom:0; /* Attaches it to the bottom */
    position:absolute; /* Changes to absolute positioning within the parent div. */
    width:100%;
}
```

That could potentially cause some unexpected behaviors though. It depends on what you're actually looking for and the content in the divs.

Comment: thanks, but i know about that, it is just not quite right for me, btw because of that positioning [green_div] stops communication with [p] and margin "brokes"(middle cell). don't have enough words to explain